# How Can I Use Components in FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, software-design

I want to use Port Maps inside of the if cases (in and gate case), but I could not use it. What is the problem? I am really new in FPGA coding. Can you help me with the code side?  When I use it before the if case, it works, but when I want to use it inside of the if case, there is a problem I could not understand.

and_Gate.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

--Project Purpose: To put A and B inputs into logical operations with gates such as and, or, nor according to the buttons...
entity and_Gate is
    Port ( 
           A_and        : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
           B_and        : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
           C_and        : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)     
         );
end and_Gate;
architecture Behavioral of and_Gate is
begin
      C_and     <= A_and and B_and;
end Behavioral;
```

arithmetic_logic_unit.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity arithmetic_logic_unit is
    generic ( 
        N : integer := 16
    );
    Port ( 
        A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
        C : out     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0) 
    );
end arithmetic_logic_unit;

architecture Behavioral of arithmetic_logic_unit is
    signal operation_type : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal C_out_and :      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    
component and_Gate is
    Port ( 
        A_and   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        B_and   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        C_and   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)        
    );
end component and_Gate;

begin
    process (A, B, operation_type)
    begin

        if (operation_type = "0101") then -- AND GATE
            and_gate1 : and_Gate port map (
                 A_and          => A,
                 B_and          => B,
                 C_and          => C_out_and
            );
                            C <= C_out_and;

        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: A process statement can only contain sequential statements. A component instantiation is a concurrent statement. A component represents a portion of a design hierarchy. An elaborated design hierarchy is static and is not conditionally present dynamically. Here the and gate wants to be always present and it's output assigned to C when operation_type = "0101". Move the component instantiation outside the process statement.

Comment: See [6. SEQUENTIAL AND CONCURRENT STATEMENTS IN THE
VHDL LANGUAGE](https://www.cse.usf.edu/~haozheng/teach/cda4253/doc/vhdl-stmt.pdf). No one ever seems to go to the trouble of listing the sequential or concurrent statements, found for example in IEEE Std 1076-2008 10. Sequential statements and 11. Concurrent statements wherein subsections would first provide syntax in an extended BNF form for the various statements followed by semantic restrictions. Learning that the reserved word **port** doesn't appear in a sequential statement is an exercise in parsing or reading error statements.

Comment: In simple words: VHDL **describes hardware**, how could it plug in or out a component if some signals changes? Think about a [breadbord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard) with the socket for your component.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment (I translated it into English) states:

> --Project Purpose: To put A and B inputs into logical operations with gates such as and, or, nor according to the buttons...

... you should improve your question to reflect better the expected result and the intention... Like the comments say, you should remember that you're describing hardware with V**HD**L. Sometimes drawing a diagram might help if it's not a complex design. Reading the language reference manual (LRM) don't help you much because you seem still to be learning the basic concepts of VHDL in general.

---

So you want to use different components to execute different logical operations (and/or/not, etc...) on signals A and B depending on the operation_type (from a button or switch), and then output the result to signal C.

Because you're designing hardware, you just cannot make the components disappear/appear depending on the value of a signal. It's hardware so the components have to be there - that's why the VHDL language doesn't allow you to do what you're trying.

Instead, you probably want to instantiate all the necessary components (AND / OR / NOT / etc...) and then select the output for the top-level design depending on the value of the signal. So something like in the following figure:

```
    ┌─────────────────────────────┐
    │    arithmetic logic unit    │
    │                             │
 A  │     ┌────────┐              │
────┼───┬─►        │ c_out_and    │
    │   │ │ and_   ├─┐            │
    │ ┌─┼─► gate   │ │  ┌───────┐ │
    │ │ │ └────────┘ └──► Multi-│ │ C
    │ │ │               │ plexer├─┼─►
    │ │ │ ┌────────┐ ┌──►       │ │
    │ │ └─► or_    │ │  └────▲──┘ │
 B  │ │   │ gate   ├─┘       │    │
────┼─┴───►        │c_out_or │    │
    │     └────────┘         │    │
    │                        │    │
    │              operation_type │
    └─────────────────────────────┘
```

---

For VHDL it would look something like this: You would have the component instantiation (port map) outside the process (because it's not a *sequential statement* but a concurrent statement in VHDL) and then selecting the output in a process, for example:

```
architecture Behavioral of arithmetic_logic_unit is
--- ...signals, component declations... omitted
begin
   and_gate1 : and_Gate port map (
        A_and          => A,
        B_and          => B,
        C_and          => C_out_and
   );
   -- Imaginary OR gate port map
   and_gate1 : or_Gate port map (
    A_or          => A,
    B_or          => B,
    C_or          => C_out_or
   );
    process (operation_type)
    begin
        if (operation_type = "0101") then -- AND GATE
            C <= C_out_and;
        else -- OR GATE
            C <= C_out_or;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture Behavioral;
```